# sessions manager not working on localhost

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am trying to create a secure session so I have copied a session manager piece of code from http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions

I am not able to log in using this session manager is my path wrong or something else not right?

```
class SessionManager
{
static function sessionStart($name, $limit = 0, $path = '/', $domain = null, 
$secure = null)
{
  // Set the cookie name before we start.
  session_name($name . '_Session');

  // Set the domain to default to the current domain.
  $domain = isset($domain) ? $domain : isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

  // Set the default secure value to whether the site is being accessed with 
SSL
  $https = isset($secure) ? $secure : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);

  // Set the cookie settings and start the session
  session_set_cookie_params($limit, $path, $domain, $secure, true);
  session_start();
}
}
```

Here is when I use the class in my login:

```
SessionManager::sessionStart('test',60, '/', '.localhost', false);
```

I have a conditional statement that directs to my logged in page and those conditions are met. (if I remove the above code it logs in just fine)

I have a header that checks on every page to make sure my session is still active(if needed I can post more code):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true && 
$_SESSION['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];)
```

this works when I just use session_start() but for some reason with this new function it doesn't...

Comment: why do you have a leading dot in   `.localhost ` ?

Comment: It was suppose to include all subdomains but it doesn't work if set to "localhost" either.